# How to implement expandable listview with more than one parent

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Hello guys I am a newbie in android I want to know if how to implement expandablelistview with more than one parent

Actually I've already created one but the problem is when i click a certain datachild in the second parent it intents the datachild of the first parent, so i want a more accurate codes of it.

here is my code

```
package com.guide.directory.school.wcc.schooldirectoryandguidematerialdesign;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ProgramsOffered extends ActionBarActivity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ProgramsOffered.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private void prepareListData() {

        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        listDataHeader.add("Courses");
        listDataHeader.add("WCC College Admision Test");
        listDataHeader.add("WCC ATC Admission Requirements");
        listDataHeader.add("Pricelist of Uniforms");
        listDataHeader.add("Pricelist of Dormitories");

        List<String> courses = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> cat = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> atc = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> uniform = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> dorm = new ArrayList<>();

        courses.add("BS Aviation Major in Commercial Flying");
        courses.add("BS Aviation Major in Aviation Management");
        courses.add("BS Aeronautical Engineering");
        courses.add("BS Tourism with Flight Attendant Course");
        courses.add("BS Aircraft Maintenance Technology");
        courses.add("Diploma in Aircraft Maintenance Technology");
        courses.add("Diploma in Avionics Technology");

        cat.add("A. Testing Fee");
        cat.add("B. Test Coverage");
        cat.add("C. Time Coverage");
        cat.add("D. Checking of CAT Paper");
        cat.add("E. Releasing of CAT Result");
        cat.add("F. Schedule of CAT");

        atc.add("Freshmen");
        atc.add("Transferees");

        uniform.add("BS Comfly and AvMgt");
        uniform.add("BS Tourism Mgt");
        uniform.add("AeroEng, AMT, Dip AvTech");

        dorm.add("Hotel");
        dorm.add("Apartment");
        dorm.add("Room");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), courses);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), cat);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), atc);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), uniform);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), dorm);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_programs_offered);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        prepareListData();
        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            int previousGroup = -1;

            public void onGroupExpand(int paramInt) {
                if (paramInt != this.previousGroup)
                    ProgramsOffered.this.expListView.collapseGroup(this.previousGroup);
                this.previousGroup = paramInt;
                Log.d("HAHA", paramInt + "");
            }
        });

        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {

            }
        });

        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView paramExpandableListView, View paramView, int paramInt1, int paramInt2, long paramLong) {
                ProgramsOffered.this.listDataHeader.get(paramInt1);
                ProgramsOffered.this.listDataChild.get(Integer.valueOf(paramInt2));
                switch (paramInt2) {
                    default:
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ProgramsOffered.this, Course1.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(ProgramsOffered.this, Course2.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(ProgramsOffered.this, Course3.class);
                        startActivity(intent2);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Intent intent3 = new Intent(ProgramsOffered.this, Course4.class);
                        startActivity(intent3);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Intent intent4 = new Intent(ProgramsOffered.this, Course5.class);
                        startActivity(intent4);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Intent intent5 = new Intent(ProgramsOffered.this, Course6.class);
                        startActivity(intent5);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Intent intent6 = new Intent(ProgramsOffered.this, Course7.class);
                        startActivity(intent6);
                        switch (paramInt2) {
                            default:
                                break;
                            case 0:
                                Intent intent7 = new Intent(ProgramsOffered.this, TestingFee.class);
                                startActivity(intent7);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                Intent intent8 = new Intent(ProgramsOffered.this, TestCoverage.class);
                                startActivity(intent8);
                        }
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
        expListView.expandGroup(0);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_programs_offered, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProgramsOffered.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is showing only one listview, where is the other?

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi hi sir, thank you for the response what do you mean where is the other?

Comment: You are saying in the question that there is more than one expandableListView. I can only see one.  ExpandableListView expListView; So what do you mean by implement more than one exp....

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi oh im sorry my bad, my real problem is 1 expandablelistview with more than one parent. I'll edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your expandable list view, each child has a groupPosition and a childPosition, so the first child in the first group is at groupPosition 0, childPosition 0. The first child in the second group would be groupPosition 1, childPosition 0.

With the way this is set up currently, in your `onChildClickListener`, `paramInt1` is the groupPosition and `paramInt2` is the child position. The Switch, Case you are using is only checking `paramInt2`, in both cases I mentioned in the first paragraph, `paramInt2` would be zero. You need to check which group(paramInt1) then which child within that group(paramInt2).

One way to do this would be to use nested Switch, Cases, so in pseudocode:

```
switch(paramInt1) {
    case 0:
        switch(paramInt2) {
            //this would be the first switch you used
                }
      break;
    case 1:
        switch (paramInt2) {
            //this would be the switch for your second group
            }
       break;
       }
```

Comment: hi sir, I did your example but when i run the app it crashed.

Comment: What does your onChildClickListener look like now, and what was the error when it crashed?

Comment: here is what onChildClickListener looks like now http://i.imgur.com/XXSaMrP.png  and the error is Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped.

Comment: uhmmm another info it seems its only crash in the first child but in the second child it seems okay.

Comment: I think it conflicts the cases :(

Comment: include a `break;` at the end of each case. I've updated my Answer to include this. You've put breaks in each case for the switch that checks paramInt2, but not in the one that checks paramInt1.